# Rails, how to store percentage values in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have dilema with storing percentage values in database. I have model "Cost" in my database. It will belong to Vat. My Vat model will have only one field: "rate". And now my problem is which type of data use. I want to store for my Vat object values something like that:

- if vat is 23% in my rate column we have 0.23.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why not just store it as float and add methods in the vat model

```
def rate
  self.rate * 100
end

def rate=(perc)
  self.rate = perc / 100
end
```

Comment: Thank's for reply. I'have idea to do this other way. I want to have a float datetype in my db. So my rate field is float. And when user type in form 23 it do before_save callback and change it to 0.23. Then I can easily pull out my vat from database and do math with costs. What you think about this?

Comment: that would definitely work, make sure you still add some convinience method to get the rate back in a `23%` form and not as `.23`. also make sure that if you add perentages the data is saved as 0.23 and you cant do rate + 5 since it would be 5.23

Comment: I would also add validation to the model to make sure that rate is between 0 and 1

Comment: Thank's for help I will do it this way.

Comment: I strongly suggesting not doing it this way. I did this in our app and just had to redo it since this method has some problems. Specifically, I had an admin form with the rate on it and when the form failed validation rails would fetch the database value for some reason and bypass my getter and setter, so 6 would become 0.06. Sometimes the admin would not notice this and it we ended up with a lot of incorrect rates in our database.

Answer (score 0):

I originally took the approach in the accepted answer and ended up having to redo the code later since it caused problems. Instead of overwriting the getters and setters I would suggest creating a separate method for use when calculating the VAT to use:

```rb
# Tax is stored as a percentage need to convert it to a decimal for usage
def rate_multiplier
  self[:rate] / 100.0
end
```